# Docker build with custom path and custom filename not working

Tags: docker, docker-build, docker-desktop

I am using Docker version 19.03.2 in Windows 10.

I have a directory `C:\docker_test` with files `Dockerfile` and `Dockerfile_test`. When I execute

```
PS C:\> docker build 'C:\docker_test'
```

in PowerShell, the image is built from `Dockerfile`, just as expected. However, when I want to build an image from `Dockerfile_test` like this

```
PS C:\> docker build -f Dockerfile_test 'C:\docker_test'
```

I get

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path:
CreateFile C:\Dockerfile_test: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't understand why Docker is looking for `C:\Dockerfile_test` although I specified a build path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should state the path (the context) of your Dockerfile, like so

```
PS C:\> docker build -f 'C:\docker_test\Dockerfile_test' 'C:\docker_test'
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I could go around specifying the complete file path. What would be a use case for a Dockerfile not being located in the build context?

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer to the question but this is to detail a bit

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

> The docker build command builds an image from a Dockerfile and a
>   context. The build’s context is the set of files at a specified
>   location PATH or URL

With `C:\docker_test` you speficied the context.

From the same docs

> Traditionally, the Dockerfile is called Dockerfile and located in the
>   root of the context. You use the `-f` flag with docker build to point to a `Dockerfile` anywhere in your file system.

Therefore if you specify the `-f` flag docker will search for the given file. In your case you have a file without path therefore docker will search in the current directory.

To make it work use the command as suggested by @Arik